# Have American universities cut back on H1-B visa sponsorship of new international faculty and F-1 student visa sponsorship for PhD students?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, faculty-application, international-students

Concerning industry, I've read that Google and Amazon have cut back significantly on its H1-B visa sponsorship of new candidates (though it's unclear what the renewal rate is for currently sponsored employees.)

Is the same sort of thing happening in academia?  Are American universities cutting back its H1-B sponsorship of new, international faculty candidates and student visa programs for its international PhD applicants?

Comment: I don't think those are really comparable.  An H1-B visa requires a lot of work on the part of the company, and legal fees that are commonly in the thousands of dollars.  Students get an F-1 visa, and all the university has to do is fill out one form and send it to the student.  The rest of the visa application process, including fees, is up to the student and costs the university nothing.

Comment: If a department is considering foreign applicants from the 7 "ban" countries or even from other majority Muslim countries (such as Pakistan, Bangladesh, Saudi Arabia, and Egypt), they might well wonder whether those students would be able to get F-1 visas to come to the US this fall.  It's certainly a potential issue for departments to consider.  I doubt that you'll be able to get an authoritative answer here, but it's something that might well be covered by news outlets like "The Chronicle Of Higher Education" in the coming months.

Comment: With respect to faculty hiring, departments might be less willing to hire faculty from the affected countries and other Muslim majority countries for fear that those faculty couldn't get H-1B visas and permanent residency.  Again, it would be challenging to document any effect, but I'd expect to see this covered by news organizations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The current ban was stopped by court, 
we are waiting if supreme  court of USA will take complaint from Trump administration but that will likely not happen because of the composition of a court. 
***Regarding American universities***, occupations that are related to academia ([post-doctoral fellow](http://www.myvisajobs.com/Research-Fellow-2016JT.htm), research fellow, etc.). You can check referenced link and put desired profession name in search menu and compare rates of awarding H1B by the universities.
Conclusion is honestly that university never awarded so much H1B in a first place, and it is a noticeable trend of declining H1B sponsored by academic institutions ( institutes, universities, hospitals... etc..)
website myvisajobs.com give you opportunity to search and compare different occupation and employees.

Comment: There are two problems with this answer.  First, although the total number of H-1B visas and green cards issued to researchers and faculty in the US may be small in comparison with the total number issued in all industries in the US the relevant question is what fraction of persons employed in those kinds of positions are getting H-1B visas.   Second, the link above points to statistics on one very narrow job classification- academics end up classified under many different categories.

Comment: "Are American universities cutting back its H1-B sponsorship of new, international faculty candidates " this was the question, I provided really nice link where you can check institution, possition and number of places granted by years. @BrianBorchers